# Using set as Primary Key in Dynamodb Index

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have created a Dynamodb model where I have set an attribute to a set using a combination of three separate id's and another attribute which takes in timestamp. The idea was to create a GIS index on these two with the set attribute as the primary key and timestamp as the sort key. While using the "equality" operator for KeyConditionExpression, I am unable to fetch the data. Not sure what the issue is. So if somebody can guide me whether I am following the right approach or I am missing something.

Below is the set attribute value sample

```
{ "291447cb-f7a5-4627-9a7e-ac7b4adf9xce", "21", "d2e5723a-437a-4517-9f4b-1a62575224d6" }
```

Comment: Please show the entire record and the code you are using to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DynamoDB can only use keys of scalar types (single value string, number or binary)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey). What you could do is concatenate the values into a string for your key (e.g. `"291447cb-f7a5-4627-9a7e-ac7b4adf9xce:21:d2e5723a-437a-4517-9f4b-1a62575224d6"`).

Don't forget in your table you'd need to store this concatenated key so it can be used in your GSI. And you'd need to make sure it's updated / kept in sync with the set as per your requirements.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. It's working.Side question, I wanted to know whether there is a way I can do something like     ("291447cb-f7a5-4627-9a7e-ac7b4adf9xce:d2e5723a-437a-4517-9f4b-1a62575224d6") and leaving the third value i.e. 21 and the query would return all the data whose Key matches the above string. I know "contains" is the one way to do it but it won't work on Key values.

Comment: Have two columns: one for the concatenation you show above, then another for "21". That way, you can use the ```"291447cb-f7a5-4627-9a7e-ac7b4adf9xce:d2e5723a-437a-4517-9f4b-1a62575224d6"``` as your GSI hash key and ```21``` as the sort key. (And pleased it's working).

Comment: Tried the same approach with some changes. Since I needed both "291447cb-f7a5-4627-9a7e-ac7b4adf9xce" and "d2e5723a-437a-4517-9f4b-1a62575224d6" in a single column and had to sort them by "ts", so I created a hash key for the one you suggested and the "ts" as the sort key and for the "21" I am using it as a FilterExpression. So in total 3 columns and I am getting the data. Let me know if this would be the right approach. Apologies for so many side questions.